# For how long does kube-state-metrics keep the metrics in its memory?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

From what I understand, kube-state-metrics keeps an in-memory cache of all the kubernetes events related to deployments, nodes and pods and more, and exposes them to `/metrics` for Prometheus to scrape.

How long does the kube-state-metrics keep these metrics in-memory? Is it indefinitely? Or does it internally clean the cache once a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most Promtheus targets, metrics are computed at scrape time. Based on [kube-state-metrics' github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/main.go), it looks like Kubernetes' implementation is no different. This means that the metrics are not cached, but rather calculated each time that the Prometheus server scrapes the endpoint (or each time you visit /metrics in your browser)

Comment: I see. So this means it probably doesn't keep a history of metrics.

Comment: Not so far as I know. Instead, the history of metrics would come from the Prometheus in its time series database (e.g. the Prometheus query `up[1h]` would show you the history of every `up` metric for the past hour).

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, I observed kube-state-metrics which referenced old nodes in metric dimension, which do not exists for several days